# Commutator with Pauli spin matrices and the momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-spin, commutator

How is $\left[\vec\sigma \cdot \vec p, \vec \sigma \right]$ proportional to $\vec \sigma\times \vec p$, where $\sigma$ are the Pauli spin matrices and $p$ is the momentum operator?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 6):

$[\vec\sigma\cdot \vec p, \vec \sigma]_i = [\sigma_j p^j, \sigma_i] = [\sigma_j , \sigma_i]p^j = 2i\epsilon_{jik} \sigma^k p^j= 2i\epsilon_{ikj} \sigma^k p^j =2i(\vec{\sigma} \times \vec{p})_i$.

So $[\vec\sigma\cdot \vec p, \vec \sigma] = 2i(\vec{\sigma} \times \vec{p}).$